# Giving the calculations result in the JFrame MessageBox

Tags: java, swing, parsing

I want my program to execute JFrame with text fields : first name, last name, account state and withdrawal amount, to ask user about that information and then show the message box like that : "Hello John Smith, after the withdrawal, your current account state is : (state after the withdrawal). I did it the only way I could (at first I wanted to create a separate class, where I would parse the state and withdrawal amount, and then make calculations, but I had problems with that). So I did it in the Card class. The problem is (this is what I want to ask you about) that the program not only doesn't make that calculations but it doesn't compile at all. When I remove the calculations code from my program, it compiles, but what's obvious, only returns "Hello firstName lastName" in the message box.

```
public class Card extends JFrame {

    private JTextField firstName;
    private JTextField lastName;
    private JTextField state;
    private JTextField withdrawal;
    private JButton accept;


    public Card() {
        super("Cash Machine");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        firstName = new JTextField("First name");
        add(firstName);

        lastName = new JTextField("Last name");
        add(lastName);

        state = new JTextField("Current account state");
        add(state);

        withdrawal = new JTextField("Amount of withdrawal");
        add(withdrawal);

        accept = new JButton("Accept");
        add(accept);


        newHandler handler = new newHandler();
        accept.addActionListener(handler);

    }
    String state1 = state.getText();
    int state2 = Integer.parseInt(state1);
    String withdrawal1 = withdrawal.getText();
    int withdrawal2 = Integer.parseInt(withdrawal1);
    int finalState = state2 - withdrawal2;



    private class newHandler implements ActionListener {

        ArrayList<String> first_names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> last_names = new ArrayList<String>();
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


            // SHOWING THE FINAL MESSAGE BOX
            if(event.getSource()==accept)

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + firstName.getText() + " " + lastName.getText() + " " + state.getText() + " .Your current account state is: " + finalState);
            }
            }       
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, my bad. All your statements out in the class were assignment statements, and so ***technically*** they are allowed, but their location is **still** giving your problems.

Your problem is you've got your calculations out in the class as part of assignment statements, and so you're doing your calculations **before** the user has had a chance to input data.

Instead, do the calculations in the **handler** class so that the text fields have some data in them.

Something like so:

```
//   String state1 = state.getText();
//   int state2 = Integer.parseInt(state1);
//   String withdrawal1 = withdrawal.getText();
//   int withdrawal2 = Integer.parseInt(withdrawal1);
//   int finalState = state2 - withdrawal2;


private class newHandler implements ActionListener {
  ArrayList<String> first_names = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> last_names = new ArrayList<String>();

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

     // SHOWING THE FINAL MESSAGE BOX
     if (event.getSource() == accept) {

        String state1 = state.getText();
        int state2 = Integer.parseInt(state1);
        String withdrawal1 = withdrawal.getText();
        int withdrawal2 = Integer.parseInt(withdrawal1);
        int finalState = state2 - withdrawal2;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + firstName.getText()
              + " " + lastName.getText() + " " + state.getText()
              + " .Your current account state is: " + finalState);
     }
  }
}
```